# MySQL connection error with native database

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have containerized a simple PHP app. It needs to connect to the host's database (localhost) and do some operations. However, while running the app, I have the following error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory ...`
My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: on-failure
```

Looks like dockerized app can't connect with localhost database. I added `network_mode: "host"`, but it didn't help.

I use Docker Desktop and Mac OS.

Comment: You are looking for host.docker.internal Take a look at this doc https://dev.to/natterstefan/docker-tip-how-to-get-host-s-ip-address-inside-a-docker-container-5anh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `localhost` I had to use `docker.for.mac.localhost` in my PHP script.